# Parsing a XDocument

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XDocument:

```
<ExtensionInfo>
  <ObjectExtension />
  <AttributeExtension>
    <Attribute Name="PV" ExtensionType="inputoutputextension" InheritedFromTagName="$CT_STQ_V2" />
    <Attribute Name="PV" ExtensionType="logdatachangeeventextension" InheritedFromTagName="$CT_STQ_V2" />
    <Attribute Name="STS" ExtensionType="inputoutputextension" InheritedFromTagName="$CT_STQ_V2" />
    <Attribute Name="STS" ExtensionType="booleanextension" InheritedFromTagName="$CT_STQ_V2" />
    <Attribute Name="STS" ExtensionType="alarmextension" InheritedFromTagName="$CT_STQ_V2" />
    <Attribute Name="STS" ExtensionType="logdatachangeeventextension" InheritedFromTagName="$CT_STQ_V2" />
  </AttributeExtension>
</ExtensionInfo>
```

I am trying to return $CT_STQ_V2 if and only if the Attribute Name="STS" and ExtensionType="alarmextension"

How can I use XDocument & LINQ query to get what I need. I need to parse through thousands of XML files so fast performance would be required. Any suggestions would help.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: Look at [this](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/query-an-xml-document-using-linq-to-xml/) blog and update your question to show your efforts.

Comment: var q1 = from elm in xd.Descendants("Attribute")
                                     where (string)elm.Attribute("Name") == myObjectReader["AttributeName"].ToString()
                                     where (string)elm.Attribute("ExtensionType") == "alarmextension"
                                     select elm;

                            foreach (var elm in q1)
                            {
                                inherited = (string)elm.Attribute("InheritedFromTagName");
                            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with simple `Linq` to `Xml` statements, my preferred choice dealing with large `Xml`s .

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

  var element = doc
      .Descendants("AttributeExtension")  // flatten the structure and look for extensions.
      .Elements("Attribute")              // get all attribute elements 
      .FirstOrDefault(x=>(string)x.Attribute("Name") == "STS" && (string)x.Attribute("ExtensionType") == "alarmextension");

  if(element!= null)
  {
      // return attribute value. 
      return (string)element.Attribute("InheritedFromTagName");
  }
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/za0zKx)